# Xcode Maven Plugin : adding extra headers

Tags: xcode, maven, build-process

The Xcode Maven Plugin from http://sap-production.github.io/xcode-maven-plugin/site is a nice maven plugin for people who like maven and wan't to avoid some pain with xcode dependencies, framework creation and such.

It creates and installs lib and headers in the repository.

The headers are bundled in a .tar file during the process.

For some reason, I need to edit the tar file and add a few files in it before installing.
But as I'm quite the noob regarding maven, I need some help !

How can I modify on a byproduct of Maven before it is installed ? I suppose I can write some script that add some files to the .taf, but how can I be sure it's executed prior the installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Redwarp - It's been a while since this question was asked, but I'll offer up an answer.

You can configure a Maven plug-in's goal to be executed during a particular phase in the Maven build lifecycle.

Pick a phase that's executed before the install phase.  Package may be the best phase for you to edit your tar file and add your required files.

The following is just a generalized example (the focus should be on phase and goal):

```
<project>
  ...
      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xcode-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.12.0</version>
                  <extensions>true</extensions>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <id>do-something</id>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <configuration>
                              ...
                          </configuration>
                          <goals>
                             <goal>plugin-goal</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Find the plug-ins that suit your needs and bind their goals to the appropriate Maven lifecycle phases...which there's a good chance that you have already figured out by this point.

Comment: That's exactly what i ended up doing ! Thanks for the answer, marking it as valid